# WPF MVVM TextBox immidiate bound property update

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM app, which shows a TextBox with its text bound to a viewmodel property:

```
    Text="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay}
```

The update of 'Caption' property happens only when putting cursor to any other control. Is there a way, a good way, to have the 'Caption' property updated immediately when typing any char? I need this because my app displays a view twice, in same window - one is real 'work area', another - a 'thumbnail', in a listbox of all loaded 'work areas'. 'Work area' would show the new text correctly. A 'thumbnail' updates the textbox only when it loses cursor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the text property, the default way to update bindings is LostFocus not PropertyChanged, you need to set this explicitly.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)